# Choice of critical/rejection region and relation of power function and type I/II error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, type-i-and-ii-errors

A hypothesis test is, fundamentally, defined by a rejection region $R$(a set of the sample $\mathbf{X}$); not by statics such as LRT and MLE etc, but by a range (*Must be so, see the following comment.*) of the statics (function of $\mathbf{X}$), since this will naturally give a range of $\mathbf{X}$ (*Comment: an echo of the definition of continuous function $f$ in topology that $f^{-1}(U_\text{an open set})=U'_\text{ an open set}$*.)

(This also suggests that a hypothesis test is closely related to an estimation of interval, e.g. the power/probability of the former being false corresponds to the probability that the parameter to be estimated is outside the latter.)

Size of a hypothesis test is the maximum $\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0} \beta(\theta)$ of probability $\beta(\theta)$($=P(\mathbf{X}\in R|\theta)$;$\beta(\theta)$ is also called power function.) that the sample $\mathbf{X}$ (not observed values, but random variables) is in the rejection region R, given that the parameter of a distribution is $\theta$ (it can be real parameter of the distribution. **Or can we think the parameter is $\theta$ (i.e. $\theta$ is not necessarily the parameter for the real distribution?) and use this as a condition for the probability?**

Either way this probability $\beta(\theta)$ is a function of $\theta$--while size $\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0} \beta(\theta)$ is not a function of $\theta$ but that of $\Theta_0$--this can be understood if we realize that the probability a random variable belongs to a region, e.g. $F(X)=P(X\in(-\infty, a))$, depends on the distribution (and its parameter) of $X$.)

**My other questions** are

1. in Casella (2nd ed.) Section 8.3.1, it's said the probability (that given a sample $\mathbf{X}$--as a set of random variables, the null hypothesis is rejected) /power function $\beta(\theta)$ (1) equals probability of type I error (accept $H_1$ when it's false), if $\theta\in\Theta_0$, (2) equals probability of type II error (accept $H_0$ when it's false), if $\theta\in\Theta_0^{c}$. Why? Would anyone give a simple explanation?

- Besides probability of type I error should be probability of rejecting $H_0$ ($\mathbf{X}\in R$) when $H_0$ is false, so it ought to be $P(\mathbf{X}\in R|H_0)$, the condition $H_0$ in my opinion should be $\theta\in \Theta_0$ or something more accurately indicating the mere fact that $H_0$ is indeed correct, something like that the distribution parameter belongs to a certain range (though not necessarily $\Theta_0$); it should not be that the distribution parameter has a specific value $\theta$, which seems too strong a condition for indicating $H_0$ is correct. So why is  probability of type I error $P(\mathbf{X}\in R|\theta)$? $\quad (1..)$

2. How do we choose $R$? If we use hypothesis test static such as LRT, then $R$ corresponds to $\{\lambda(\mathbf{X})< \text{or }> c\}$, i.e. $R=\lambda^{-1}((0,c) \text{ or } (c,1))$, and what we need is just to determine c and </>. (I'm not clear how to make such a decision.)
   We can also choose not to use LRT, but directly set an $R$, (Example 8.3.2). So generally, what is the rule of choosing $R$?
3. The power function $\beta(\theta)$ can be interpreted as the probability of type I error (or 1 minus the probability of type II error), how do we interpret size (supremum of $\beta(\theta)$)?

- (*Updated:* things are clear if we consider the usual case of simple $H_0$, we see here the probability of type I error is the same as size, and so for composite $H_0$ the size is also an indicator of type I error, more exactly, the largest type I error for all cases that $H_0$ is correct; and the discussion of (1..) is also simple, since $H_0$ being correct is the same as $\theta_0$ being correct. From these we see the size $\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0} \beta(\theta)=\alpha$ actually says that for each of null hypotheses, the type I error is guaranteed to be less than $\alpha$; so what we do is we don't directly calculate the type I error (of a hypo test) for a composite $H_0$, $P(\mathbf{X}\in R| H_0)$, (e.g.$P(\mathbf{X}\in R| p<\frac 1 2)$, $X$~nominal (n,p))--perhaps because it's a intimidatingly complex question--instead, we break down the composite $H_0$ to simple null hypotheses, and calculate type I error for each of them, and we calculate the upper limit of them, i.e. *size*, or set (or find) an upper bound to them, i.e. *level*. $\quad (2..)$)
- Besides, level $\alpha$ is defined as a set upper bound for size, so it's sort of set upper bound of supremum of $\beta(\theta)$, how do we interpret this?
- (*Updated:* from (2..) we see level is just an 'approximation' of size, for reasons like that sometimes we need not exact values of size but just need to know or ensure the size is small enough, then we can just find an upper bound of the size of the hypothesis test. This is similar to that often we need not calculate the exact p-value, but give confidence level to tell, for example, if a test static is equal to the mean of a distribution.)

PS: a summary of how to calculate size of a hypothesis test. First we have a hypothesis test static $T(\mathbf{X})$, and determine its region $U$, the inverse map of $U$ will give a set of $\mathbf{X})$, i.e. a rejection region $R$ (we can also directly pick $R$.) Then we calculate the probability that $\mathbf{X})\in R$, since $X$ has a distribution parameterized by $\theta$, this probability is a function $\beta(\theta)$ of $\theta$ ( $\theta$ is not limited to $\Theta_0$, even if we have $\theta\in\Theta_0$ in the nominator of LRT--this doesn't limit range of $\theta$, actually it's not *directly* a function of $\theta$, but one of $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta$, that is, LRT is completely determined by an *observed* sample and null hypothesis; instead, it's a function of $\mathbf{X}$, and so a random variable, and so the *probability* that it picks certain value--here the sample is not yet *observed* but can possibly pick up many values--is a function of the distribution (parameter) of $\mathbf{X}$) And this $\beta(\theta)$ has a supremum (size) for $\theta$ in a chosen set, like $\Theta_0$.

In reverse, (and in practice,) the test static $T(\mathbf{X})$'s region $U$ is usually unspecified, and so we can not only use the size to evaluate a hypothesis test, but also use the size (the maximum probability of type I error for $\theta$ in certain range ($\Theta_0$)--I'm not sure why the author says after Definition 8.3.6 that the size/level doesn't control the type II error) to choose a proper range $U$ (and so a proper $R$). The ways of evaluating a hypothesis test is often used to pick one from a family (if the test contains some parameter) of tests, and this is also so for estimation of interval.

Comment: Well I feel in statistics it's, heretofore, not that maths is difficult but the way that definitions are given is difficult for me to understand naturally. If I try patiently some examples I may figure out, perhaps I hurry too much.

Comment: It seems the meaning of definitions of a hypothesis test/estimator of interval often make sense only after one learns their evaluation, i.e. after one knows how to calculate the probability of the test/estimate of interval being correct/wrong. It's only then that one can justify these test/estimator, and it's only  there that probability theories come into play. Before that point everything is like 'probably correct, sounding reasonable', but very much unjustified, i.e. empirically valid, but unsound.

Comment: The simplest example where $H_0$ is simple is often illuminating.

Comment: The example of the relation btwn probability of type I error and size actually implies that when statisticians develop statistical tools they don’t always choose the most reasonable way, instead, I guess particularly when they deal with complicated situations, they borrow tools from maths since they are mathematicians, (The above example is an analog of sth like uniform continuity.) these tools may not be conceptually reasonable but already exist and are convenient to use. In other words these tools are (though not conceptually) conventionally reasonable. This shows that science is convention.

Comment: I think this perspective is a key to understanding something in maths/statistics/science that is not conceptually accessible but still reasonable; one should think of them as an analog of preexisting maths tools/concepts, and interpret the former in the light of how the latter makes sense.

Comment: This example also shows that the language of statistics is similar to that of physics, not exact; **if you wanna know the exact meaning you have to look at the math formula**. For example, power function $\beta(\theta)$ doesn’t give type I error for test about composite hypothesis, (but gives the error for each of (simple) hypothesis) nor does size or level. The size or level is simply the/an upper bound  for all these errors, not an error for test about a composite hypothesis. In other words, statistics is indeed much unlike maths, theo/appl stat is more like theo/appl phys in language style.

Comment: The point is that to get an accurate understanding you need to be *careful* about the verbal description.